# why I can't embed my template in the main theme in prestashop 1.7?

Tags: php, module, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to follow the official guide of prestashop but I am facing 2 issues:

1. I see the display.tpl as raw text and not embedded in the main theme.
2. I can't see the message stored in the variable "my_module_message"

> g2a.php (the main module file)

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($param)
{
    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array(
            'my_module_name' => configuration::get('G2A_NAME'),
            'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('g2a','display'),
            'my_module_message' => $this->l('This is a simple text message')));

    return $this->display(__FILE__ , 'g2a.tpl');
}
```

> controllers/front/display.php

```
class g2adisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();
     $this->context->smarty->assign('my_module_message', $this->l('This is a simple text message'));
        $this->setTemplate('module:g2a/views/templates/front/display.tpl');
  }
}
```

> views/templates/front/display.tpl

```
    {extends file=$layout}

{block name='content'}
  welcome to my shop!
  {$my_module_message}
{/block}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The first one:**
you pass your `my_module_message` variable to your `mymodule.tpl` template but not to your `display.tpl` which is rendered earlier. So you need to pass that variable from your controller class before setting a template. You can do this by the same way

```
class mymoduleDisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('my_module_message', $this->l('This is a simple text message'));
        $this->setTemplate('module:mymodule/views/templates/front/display.tpl');
    }
}
```

and ,by the way, it is better to name your class according to camelcase conventions rules.

**The second one:**
to get your code embedded into a page you have to extend it and override or fill that part which you need. For example, if you want your code to be a main content of the page you need to do the next in your `display.tpl`

```
{extends file=$layout}

{block name='content'}
  welcome to my shop!
{/block}
```

Comment: I checked it out one more time and everything works as expected. What do you get when you put this link to your browser your_domain/index.php?fc=module&module=mymodule&controller=display?

Comment: I just modified the code in the main question so the file names and classes names be more clear. the url you mentioned gives me this message "The page you are looking for was not found." also this is the link that shows in the browser when I try to test my code. "http://localhost/sitefolder/en/module/g2a/display". and it always gives me a blank row page with the text in it and without the variable "my_module_message". also I tried to show   {$layout} but it gives me nothing.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it also works for me after changing that you have mentioned above. What theme do you use? And if you want to print variable $layout you must do it inside a {block name='content'}. And may it be possible that you have an override file for your views/templates/front/display.tpl?

Comment: you where right, the code is correct. but it was a cache issue. please check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the code is correct but because I disabled cache in the admin panel i didn't think it is a cache issue.

> **Admin** > **Configure** > **Advanced Parameters** > **Performance** > **Smarty** > **Template compilation** > *Recompile templates if the files have been updated*.